# ldapsearch filter with dn

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I wanted to search for mentioned entity from the ldapsearch:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -x -H ldaps://ldapserver -E pr=1000/noprompt -b "O=XXX,C=AN " "(dn=cn=firstName lastName  1231233,ou=employee,o=xxx,c=an)"
```

I get the output as

```
# pagedresults: cookie=
```

But when i search the same entity with its alias name, I am getting the whole object return from the command.

So, why I am not getting the return from the mentioned command.

I wanted to do the filter on the dn field from the as already mentioned and the same dn I got from the alias search field. So ideally I should get the result if I used the correct way to filter.

Please let me know if I made any mistake on the filter query.

Comment: You don't need to search for a DN. You can access it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the entry by its dn using the following (probably what @user207421 suggested) :

```
ldapsearch -LLL -x -H ldaps://ldapserver -b "cn=firstName lastName  1231233,ou=employee,o=xxx,c=an" -s base
```

The key is to set the searched entry as the base with the appropriate scope, that is *base*.